# how to make common custom package for authentication in laravel 5.8 or 6.*

Tags: mysql, laravel, mongodb, eloquent, model

I have to make custom common package for authentication in a laravel, but having one problem is whenever I'm using MongoDB that package is not working, & while using MySQL everything is fine. because of laravel models, MySQL working with eloquent model & MongoDB is working with jessengers model. so having any idea or trick to use a single model for different Databases?

While using MySql

```php
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable {
         protected $table = 'users';
    }
```

and in MongoDB

```php
    use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable {
          protected $collection = 'users';
    }
```

and getting error like

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function prepare() on null in file /var/www/test-authentication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php

Comment: "not working" errors? Unexpected results? Can you show the code? Which MongoDB/MySQL versions have been tested?

Comment: Now, I have fully described, in short, I want to use a single model while the database is in MongoDB or MySQL

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this :

```
$user = (new \App\User(['name'=>'FirstName', 'email'=>'testemail@email.com']))->setConnection('x-DB');
$user->save();

// without models
(new \App\User(['name'=>'My Name', x-'email'=>'testmail@email.com']))>setConnection('x-DB')->save();
```

Its working as `create` is a static method that instantiates new static, so it uses `default connection`.
 Check this out, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Comment: Share your error details, also try to use dd(); to debug. and see what you are getting there.

Comment: Please check, I have edited my question. and added error line too

Comment: Have you registered MongoDB service provider, register the MongodbServiceProvider.

`'providers' => [
        Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,
           ]`